# Difference between isNetworkUrl and isValidUrl

Tags: java, android

I would like to know what is the difference between a URL and a Network URL.

```
public static boolean isNetworkUrl (String url)

public static boolean isValidUrl (String url)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil.html#isValidUrl%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seeing the source code and documentation for both the functions:-

isValidUrl returns true if the url is a valid url of any url type(http url / file url etc).

```
  public static boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
      if (url == null || url.length() == 0) {
          return false;
      }

      return (isAssetUrl(url) ||
             isResourceUrl(url) ||
               isFileUrl(url) ||
               isAboutUrl(url) ||
             isHttpUrl(url) ||
             isHttpsUrl(url) ||
             isJavaScriptUrl(url) ||
            isContentUrl(url));
   }
```

Whereas isNetworkUrl returns true only if the url is a http / https url (i.e a network url adressing a network resource based on http protocol )

```
 public static boolean isNetworkUrl(String url) {
       if (url == null || url.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return isHttpUrl(url) || isHttpsUrl(url);
   }
```

Reference for source code:- <strike>http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/webkit/URLUtil.java#URLUtil.isNetworkUrl%28java.lang.String%29</strike>

Edit (20 june 2020):
The url above is broken now, [New url](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/webkit/URLUtil.java) from official android pages: